# Django запрет на изменение всех полей формы

Tags: python-3.x, django

Изучаю Django, есть форма без привязки к модели. Форма описывает атрибуты Active Directory

**forms.py**

```
class UserDetailForm(forms.Form):

    # Personal Information
    company         = forms.CharField()
    employeeID      = forms.CharField()
    sAMAccountName  = forms.CharField()
    title           = forms.CharField()
    ...
    department      = forms.CharField()
```

Можно ли сделать все поля Readonly глобально, не описывая каждое поле повторно. Пока нашел только способ:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['company'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    self.fields['employeeID'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    self.fields['sAMAccountName'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    ...
    self.fields['department'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Comment: Пройтись циклом по всем полям и выставить каждому `readonly = True`

Comment: `for field in self.fields:
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True` - как-то так, может. Не пробовал.